# Locking editing of Rows or Columns in Google Doc Spreadsheets with Auto fill

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do one lock editing of a column (row) or columns (rows) using a script in Google spreadsheet not to be affected by an auto fill operation on the column (row). Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately Google has not released a method for blocking cell is only available to block the entire page as code below.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var permissions = sheet.getSheetProtection();
permissions.addUser('user@example.com');
permissions.setProtected(true);
sheet.setSheetProtection(permissions);
```

I have followed the roadmap of them and it is possible that this feature is released between the next two months.